# What is the scope of a namespace alias?

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces, namespace-alias

Does a C++ namespace alias defined inside a function definition have a block, function, file, or other scope (duration of validity)?

Comment: Do you mean "using [namespace];" ?

Comment: It looks like he means the aliasing of a longer namespace name to that of a more easily used identifier: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chwe1tc8.aspx

Comment: namespace alias (and using declarations) have the same scoping rules as other declarations in C++.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a block duration of validity.

For example: If you define a namespace alias as below, the namespace alias abc would be invalid outside the `{...}`-block.

```cpp
{  
    namespace abc = xyz;
    abc::test t;  //valid 
}
abc::test t;  //invalid
```

Answer (score 1):

The scope is the declarative region in which the alias is defined.

Answer (score 0):

It would have the scope of the block in which it was defined - likely to be the same as function scope unless you declare the alias inside a block within a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain that a namespace alias only has scope within the block it's created in, like most other sorts of identifiers. I can't check for sure at the moment, but [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chwe1tc8.aspx) doesn't seem to go against it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it's in the scope it's declared. So, if you alias in a method, then it's valid in that method, but not in another.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/Scope/Namespaces

Answer (score 0):

It is valid for the duration of the scope in which it is introduced.

Take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias, I trust the explanation of cppreference, it's much more standard.

Comment: Please don't provide only a link. Also add at least a partial excerpt from the page you are referencing.